# Получение responce ответа и конвертация с сохранением в json через Playwright

Tags: c#, json, response, playwright

Я хочу получить тело из Response ответа и сохранить его для дальнейших манипуляций.
При нажатии на кнопку, отправляются POST запросы и мне необходимо из множества найти тот у которого в в теле будет указан метод "getElementData". После получить данные из тела и вернуть из метода.

Но проблема заключается в том что вернуть я их не могу получая ошибку "Анонимная функция, преобразованная в делегата, возвращающего void, не может возвращать значение."
Код который я указал полностью работает но не дает мне сохранить найденный мной Response.
Каким способом я могу сохранить текст тела для дальнейших проверок?

Стек: C# + Playwright

```
//Создаем переменую для хранения данных полученых от Response
    Dictionary<string, string> ts = new();
    //Вводим информацию
    await EnterInfo(info, log);
    log.AddInfoLog("Начинаем прослушку Response");
    //Начинаем слушать все ответы с сервера
    Page.Response += async (_, response) => {
        //Получем ответы в виде json
        JsonElement? jsonElement = await response.JsonAsync();
        //Переводим ответ в текс
        string? jsonText = jsonElement.ToString();
        //Проверяем что бы ответ не оказался пустым
        if(jsonText != null){
            //Находим нужный нам метод в ответах
            if(JsonFileSystem.ReturnMethodTSFromJson(jsonText) == "getElementData"){
                log.AddInfoLog("В Response ответе найден метод getElementData");
                //Получаем всю информацию в виде Dictionary<string, string>
                return JsonFileSystem.ReturnInfoTSFromJson(jsonText);
                log.AddInfoLog($"Получен ответ из метода getElementData:");
                foreach(var element in ts){
                    log.AddInfoLog($"Key = {element.Key}, Value = {element.Value}");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    foreach(var element in ts){
        NUnit.Framework.TestContext.Progress.WriteLine($"Key = {element.Key}, Value = {element.Value}");
    }
    //Проверяем что переменая не пустая и возвращем её
    if(ts != null){
        return ts;
    }
    
    //Если пустая выкидываем ошибку
    throw new Exception("Ошибка при получении запроса по информации Response (CreateBasePage -> getInfoMethod)");
```

Comment: Как по мне, очень странный код. 1. Я надеюсь вы не парсите сайт при помощи того, что создано для тестирования? Если да, то советую всеж разобрать сайт, посмотреть его запросы и работать с сервером напрямую, а не вот это вот все. 2. JSON десериализуют в конкретный класс, а не вот так вот разбивают, получают потом что-то, сверяют со строкой, и так далее. Возьмите JSON, создайте класс, далее пишите условно `if (result.ElementData?.Value is {} { // Делаем что-то }`, все, зачем вот это вот все в вашем коде я лично не понимаю.